# Comparing images in N channels

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, data, similarity, image-size

I have an "image" of NxN dimensions in m channels (for reference, m is less than 17) in my training set and validation set. I would like to compare images in the training set with those in the validation set and get a similarity index for each image (which I can then try to turn into some sort of statistical measure for the similarity for the whole set). I saw that there is imagehash tool for comparing RGB images but I was wondering if there is a package for comparing images in m channels?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image can be loaded as a PIL instance, then Python's [imagehash](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/imagehash/blob/master/examples/hashimages.py) library will be able to perform similarity-based hashing.

Comment: Thanks! For now, we found other ways to proceed but I will keep this in mind.